# Paperclip reprocess returns true but doesn't change folders structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a problem with paperclip. I set it to store my attachments in s3 and I have a lot of them in original size. The problem is I need to reprocess them to have 3 diffrent sizes per image. I read in paperclip readme that #reprocess! method might be useful.

This is my user class with attachment :

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles:
{
  large: ["135x135#", :jpg],
  thumb: ["50x50#", :jpg],
  small: ["30x30#", :jpg]
},
default_url: '/placeholders/avatars/:style.png',
url: '/system/users/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
storage: :s3,
bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
s3_credentials: {
  :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
}

validates_attachment :avatar,
content_type: {
  content_type: /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/,
  message: 'is not allowed (only images)'
},
size: {
  in: 0..1.megabytes,
  message: 'is too big'
}
```

I have also set credentials to s3 in my development.rb and production.rb. When I ran reprocess! on every user.avatar object it returns true but folder structure don't change.

```
pry(#<Importer::Mugshots>)> user.avatar.reprocess!
(0.6ms)  BEGIN
(5.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "avatar_content_type" = '', "avatar_file_size" = 30735, "avatar_updated_at" = '2013-11-19 11:10:17.486960', "avatar_file_name" = '78398594.jpg', "updated_at" = '2013-11-19 11:10:19.001503' WHERE "users"."id" = 542025
(11.6ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

I tried to change paperclip config to use local filesystem but it doesn't help. What it might be ?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs like `[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /dir/file.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>`? This would indicate the `reprocess!` is failing because the original is not available locally, because it’s been uploaded to S3.

Answer (score 0):

try to move the bucket inside the s3_credentials hash

```
s3_credentials: {
 :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET']
 :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
 :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
}
```